Topics in Probability Theory to focus on.
I like pure mathematics. I used to like topology and Geometry. I have read commutative algebra by M.Atiyah and did my MS thesis in Cohomology of smooth manifolds. I like pure mathematics, structure, deep theorems and possible connection to theoretical physics.
Due to some constraints, I can't do phd in the above fields, but in Probability Theory. Which subfield of probability theory to focus on, given that I like pure mathematics, structure and advanced ties to physics. I am currently reading "Robert Ash's Probability and Measure Theory"

There is an area in probability theory that rigorously studies ideas motivated by statistical physics, focusing on the large-scale (and limiting) behavior of random structures and emergent phenomena. I don't think there is a single name for this field, but it encompasses the study of various structures, including but not limited to, Brownian objects, percolation models, lattice systems, Gaussian free fields, interacting particle systems, random matrices, just to name a few. This book might be a good starting point to grasp some ideas.
